# Using Array Sort <strings> <integers>

Tags: .net

Im working on a console application which sends and receives data through a WinSock control. for each incremental stream that gets added to the buffer i have generated an array list and appended incoming integral address (IPv4) from the stream. however, while listing the data in another control, it appears in Unsorted manner.

```
Private Sub clrHandler_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles clrHandler.Click
dim clrReckon as Integer
clrReckon = PostCLRCount
PostCLRCount += 1
```

Comment: I notice you've misspelt `Integer`. You should always copy your code when posting, don't attempt to re-type it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the values in an Array, or other Collection, and use [Array.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

If you store them in separate variables then you would need to write the code that sorts them.

Comment: Knowing how to use arrays is fundamental to any programming language, so you should study how to use them.

Comment: Yes. That's possible.

Comment: Yes, it will be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 5 integer values for each of the button click counts, then you can order them in ascending order like this:

```
Public Class ButtonCount
Private m_Name As String
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return m_Name
        End Get
        Set
            m_Name = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_Count As Integer
    Public Property Count() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_Count
        End Get
        Set
            m_Count = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New(name As String, count As Integer)
        Name = name
        Count = count
    End Sub
End Class

Dim listButtonCount As New List(Of ButtonCount)()
listButtonCount.Add(New ButtonCount("A", aCount))
listButtonCount.Add(New ButtonCount("B", bCount))
listButtonCount.Add(New ButtonCount("C", cCount))
listButtonCount.Add(New ButtonCount("D", dCount))
listButtonCount.Add(New ButtonCount("E", eCount))
```

Note: `aCount`, `bCount`, `cCount`, `dCount` and `eCount` are the five `Integer` values you are keeping track of for clicks of the respective buttons.

```
Dim sortedListButtonCount As List(Of ButtonCount) = listButtonCount.OrderBy(Function(c) c.Count).ToList()
```